# Latest maven dependency version for pentao kettle

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I want to mavenize pentaho kettle plugin development, and using below xml code in pom.xml to upgrade the current version 4.4.0 stable to the latest one.
I Used 6.0.0.1-364 , but 6.1 is stable latest according to pentaho site. Then what is the corresponding maven dependency for the same?

Here http://repo.pentaho.org/content/grou...e/kettle-core/ I can see the list of kettle maven dependencies . But which one is latest and stable version ? Please help me understand

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
<artifactId>kettle-core</artifactId>
<version>6.0.0.1-364</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
<artifactId>kettle-engine</artifactId>
<version>6.0.0.1-364</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
<artifactId>kettle-ui-swt</artifactId>
<version>6.0.0.1-364</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAK you should use the maven dependency corresponding to the PDI version installed in your system. So if you are using Kettle version of 6.0.0.1-364 then use the same maven dependency. Now from the above [link](http://repo.pentaho.org/content/groups/omni/pentaho-kettle/kettle-core/), it seems that the latest version is 6.1.0.2-208. If you are looking for the latest version, it is 6.1.0.2

POM link: http://repo.pentaho.org/content/groups/omni/pentaho-kettle/kettle-core/6.1.0.2-208/kettle-core-6.1.0.2-208.pom

Hope it helps :)